# How to make request without blocking (using asyncio)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio

I would like to achieve the following using `asyncio`:

```
# Each iteration of this loop MUST last only 1 second
while True:
    # Make an async request

    sleep(1)
```

However, the only examples I've seen use some variation of

```
async def my_func():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, 'http://www.google.com')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(my_func())
```

But `run_until_complete` is blocking! Using `run_until_complete` in each iteration of my `while` loop would cause the loop to block.

I've spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out how to correctly run a non-blocking task (defined with `async def`) without success. I must be missing something obvious, because something as simple as this should surely be simple. How can I achieve what I have described?

Comment: The loop itself will always be blocking. Ideally you’d want to put your while inside a coroutine run by your loop, but without a better idea of how your code is supposed to work, it’s hard to say much more.

Comment: hello, I find myself in this exact situation where *All I want is to have normal synchronous execution...* (inside a while loop)  *...with the ability to call async methods when needed. I don't care about the result.* Were you able to achieve this??? please, thanks

Comment: In JavaScript this is trivial to achieve, pity Python makes it so hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run_until_complete` runs the main event loop. It's not "blocking" so to speak, it just runs the event loop until the coroutine you passed as a parameter returns. It has to hang because otherwise, the program would either stop or be blocked by the next instructions.

It's pretty hard to tell what you are willing to achieve, but this piece code actually does something:

```
async def my_func():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        res = await loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, 'http://www.google.com')
        print(res)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(my_func())
```

It will perform a GET request on Google homepage every seconds, popping a new thread to perform each request. You can convince yourself that it's actually non-blocking by running multiple requests virtually in parallel:

```
async def entrypoint():
    await asyncio.wait([
        get('https://www.google.com'),
        get('https://www.stackoverflow.com'),
    ])

async def get(url):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        res = await loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, url)
        print(url, res)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(entrypoint())
```

Another thing to notice is that you're running requests in separate threads each time. It works, but it's sort of a hack. You should rather be using a real asynchronus HTTP client such as [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Thanks, this makes things a little clearer, but wouldn't this also make my `while` loop be asynchronous (when I don't want it to be, as shown in my example)?

All I want is to have normal synchronous execution with the ability to call async methods when needed. I don't care about the result. With threading this was simple - `Thread().start()`. Perhaps using `asyncio` just needs a major mindset change on my part.

Comment: asyncio indeed requires you to change the whole paradigm of your application. Imagine you call `run_until_complete` and it does not hang. Just after it, you might call `time.sleep(5)` which **is a blocking function**. In fact, any function you would call after would never give a chance to the event loop to poll. Coroutines would never execute because the event loop isn't running/polling (remember: all this happens on one only thread). If you need to call blocking functions later on, do it in another thread (using `run_in_executor`) or run the whole event loop in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

**This is Python 3.10**

`asyncio` is single threaded execution, using await to yield the cpu to other function until what is await'ed is done.

```
    import asyncio
    async def my_func(t):
        print("Start my_func")
        await asyncio.sleep(t)  # The await yields cpu, while we wait
        print("Exit my_func")

    async def main():
        asyncio.ensure_future(my_func(10)) # Schedules on event loop, we might want to save the returned future to later check for completion.
        print("Start main")
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # The await yields cpu, giving my_func chance to start.
        print("running other stuff")
        await asyncio.sleep(15)
        print("Exit main")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        asyncio.run(main())  # Starts event loop
```